# Laravel (v5.2.45) Seeder and double quotes

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I am trying to use a Laravel (v5.2.45) DB Seeder to initiate a lookups table in a Postgres DB.

When I run it, I get this output:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "lkup_type" of relation "syslookups" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into "syslookups" ("lkup_type", "lkup_text") values (...
                               ^ (SQL: insert into "syslookups" ("lkup_type", "lkup_text") values (0, Employee))
```

Here's the seeder code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class SyslookupsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('syslookups')->delete();

        DB::table('syslookups')->insert(
            ['lkup_type'=>0, 'lkup_text'=>"Employee"],
            ['lkup_type'=>0, 'lkup_text'=>"Member"],
            ['lkup_type'=>1, 'lkup_text'=>"Open"],
            ['lkup_type'=>1, 'lkup_text'=>"Closed"],
            // .. many more here
            ['lkup_type'=>5, 'lkup_text'=>"Yes"],
            ['lkup_type'=>5, 'lkup_text'=>"No"],
            ['lkup_type'=>6, 'lkup_text'=>"Work Phone"],
            ['lkup_type'=>6, 'lkup_text'=>"Fax"],
            ['lkup_type'=>6, 'lkup_text'=>"Home Phone"],
            ['lkup_type'=>6, 'lkup_text'=>"Cell Phone"]
        );    
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can make it NOT use the double quotes? I have tried with double quotes around the table name and column names with same result.
The table has a serial column called `lkup_id` and the default `created_at` and `updated_at` columns, do I need to seed those, too?

**EDIT**

I have found the line causing the double quotes. PostgresGrammar.php, `function wrapValue()` but when I change this line:

```
return '"'.str_replace('"', '""', $value).'"';
```

to this:

```
return str_replace('"', '""', $value);
```

I get this error now:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "lkup_type" of relation "syslookups" does not exist
 LINE 1: insert into syslookups (lkup_type, lkup_text) values ($1, $2...
                             ^ (SQL: insert into syslookups (lkup_type, lkup_text) values (0, Employee))
```

This, to me looks to be correct SQL for Postgres...

Comment: I don't understand why the quotes are the issue. Does the table have a `lkup_type` column?

Comment: Yes, but Postgres doesn't like the double quotes around the table and column names.

Comment: Double quotes are the delimiters for identifiers in PostgreSQL. Is the column's name *exactly* `lkup_type` (all lowercase)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the line causing the double quotes. In `PostgresGrammar.php`,
 `function wrapValue()` change this line:

```
return '"'.str_replace('"', '""', $value).'"';
```

to this:

```
return str_replace('"', '""', $value);
```

I also found out that I was not prepending the schema name on my tablename AND the column names were actually incorrect. Damn old eyes, I guess ;-)

I also needed to reset the serial sequence for the lkp_id column, which is not updated in the seeder. I will add the created_at and updated_at values later. Thanks for looking at this...

```
DB::table('eddie.syslookups')->delete();
DB::statement('ALTER SEQUENCE eddie.syslookups_lkp_id_seq RESTART');
DB::table('eddie.syslookups')->insert([
    ['lkp_type'=>0, 'lkp_text'=>"Employee"],
    ['lkp_type'=>0, 'lkp_text'=>"Member"],
    ['lkp_type'=>1, 'lkp_text'=>"Open"],
    ['lkp_type'=>1, 'lkp_text'=>"Closed"],
    ['lkup_type'=>1, 'lkup_text'=>"Closed"],
    // .. many more here
    ['lkup_type'=>5, 'lkup_text'=>"Yes"],
    ['lkp_type'=>5, 'lkp_text'=>"No"],
    ['lkp_type'=>7, 'lkp_text'=>"Work Phone"],
    ['lkp_type'=>7, 'lkp_text'=>"Fax"],
    ['lkp_type'=>7, 'lkp_text'=>"Home Phone"],
    ['lkp_type'=>7, 'lkp_text'=>"Cell Phone"]]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's query builder appears to always place column names inside of double quotes for Postgres.  I don't see any option for disabling this and I don't use postgres.

A way around this in the query builder would be to place your column names in raw expressions, but this wouldn't work with your insert statement because a raw expression would be an invalid key for an array.

It seems, if you don't want to write your own driver or modify Laravel's code, you'd have to use a raw statement for this.

```
DB::insert('INSERT INTO syslookups (lkup_type, lkup_text) ...');
```

Long story short, Laravel, perhaps incorrectly, assumes all columns should be quoted so you may want to make sure your table definitions match this convention.

Comment: It is supposed to happen ONLY if you have capital letters in your table or column names, then Postgres will allow it.

Comment: @MB34 I don't know what to tell you, don't use postgres and wasn't involved in the creation of the driver for postgres.   Did you create your tables with Laravel migrations or did you create them on your own?

Comment: You can't just up and tell someone to not use Postgres. This app is using a DB that has been in use for years within our company.

Comment: @MB34, I was saying I don't use postgres.  No need to be hostile.

Comment: Well you just can't say to not use it if you don't know the circumstances.It has more to do with Postgres than Laravel. Laravel was written as more of a port of Ruby on Rails and Ruby has the same issue with Postgres, see:
http://blog.lerner.co.il/quoting-postgresql/ Laravel needs to change their query builder

Comment: I didn't... lol.  You must not understand English context very well.  "don't use postgres and wasn't involved" was still in the first person context meaning "I don't use postgres and I wasn't involved".   You should stop being hostile to people trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry, misread, I guess. This has just been very frustrating. Something that I think should have been fixed ages ago. It may be fixed in later versions but I cannot use them due to the PHP version I am required to support.

Comment: Understandable,  and it's doubtful to get a fix for an older version, but since 5.2 is end of life, you probably could just modify the grammar class being used for Postgres and remove the quotes.

Comment: Gotta find where it is happening. It isn't shown in the exception.

Comment: It'd most likely be in a class called PostgresGrammar

Comment: I found it but am not sure how to change it...`function wrapValue()` - `return '"'.str_replace('"', '""', $value).'"';`